# Bottom Padding In Vim?

Tags: neovim, scrolling, movement

My (n)vim window looks like this:

[image: no padding]

Line 91 is the end of the document, and it's flush with the document name at the bottom (essentially the bottom of the screen). How do I "move" that line upwards towards the center like this, as though the document is just shorter than it is?

[image]

I don't want to just add a bunch of newlines. Is there any way to pad out the bottom of the document? Thanks!

Sorry about the question tags, I'm not really sure what they should be.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I believe we may have some duplicates of this lying around, but in the meantime, have an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be looking for `zz`, `zt`, and `zb`—they center (or move to the top, or to the bottom) the current line on the screen.